# How to show my source code in stack trace for Xamarin iOS app?

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.ios, mono

My Xamarin iOS app crashes with error "unrecognized selector sent to instance...", but neither the stack trace nor the call stack has any useful information of where could be the problem in my source code. I'm using Visual Studio for Mac, and the app is running on the iOS simulator. Are there any options that need to be enabled in order to show my source code in the stack trace?

```
Unhandled Exception:
Foundation.MonoTouchException: Objective-C exception thrown.  Name: NSInvalidArgumentException Reason: -[NSObject doesNotRecognizeSelector]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x600000016d80
Native stack trace:
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010579e12b __exceptionPreprocess + 171
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00000001066d8f41 objc_exception_throw + 48
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010581f024 -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 132
    3   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000105720f78 ___forwarding___ + 1432
    4   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000105720958 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 120
    5   Foundation                          0x0000000103997f35 __NSFireDelayedPerform + 409
    6   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010572e174 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_TIMER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 20
    7   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010572de32 __CFRunLoopDoTimer + 1026
    8   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010572d9ea __CFRunLoopDoTimers + 266
    9   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000105725404 __CFRunLoopRun + 2308
    10  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000105724889 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 409
    11  GraphicsServices                    0x0000000108cfb9c6 GSEventRunModal + 62
    12  UIKit                               0x00000001013375d6 UIApplicationMain + 159
    13  ???                                 0x00000001179fbe98 0x0 + 4691312280
    14  ???                                 0x00000001179fbac3 0x0 + 4691311299
```

[image]

[image]

**Update:**

The problem seems related to [.dSYM files not being generated](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/187/how-do-i-generate-dsym-for-simulator) for the simulator.

Comment: I don't understand your question. You have the line in your source that is raising the exception already highlighted; it's the one and only line of code you have in your `Main` function. That's the only information that is available to you in the stack trace or call stack that is relevant to your own code. There's absolutely nothing more that the stack trace or call stack can show you than what is already displaying.

Comment: @KenWhite Xamarin iOS always shows the same line of code in Main.cs because that's the entry point for the application, what I do is to continue the app execution, and then the stack trace that appears in the application output shows the proper line where the exception occurred in some other file than Main.cs. I thought it was a bug in the framework or the runtime, but for this particular error I can't get any useful information by continuing the app execution.

Comment: Add `-gcc_flags -ObjC` to the additional mtouch arguments or modify the LinkWith attribute , details refer to [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30892663/8187800).

Answer (score 3):

This is what I add to my `Application.cs` class to better see exception information:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
#if DEBUG
        try
        {
#endif
            UIApplication.Main(args, null, "AppDelegate");
#if DEBUG
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            var msg = ex.Message;
            var temp = ex.StackTrace;
            if(System.Diagnostics.Debugger.IsAttached)
                System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break();
            throw;
        }
#endif
    }
```

Comment: The problem seems related to [.dSYM files not being generated](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/187/how-do-i-generate-dsym-for-simulator) for the simulator, any workaround for that?

Comment: Not a perfect solution, but I can at least see the stack trace in the console now.

Answer (score 0):

You can trace inside xamarin source code.  [Details specified in Microsoft documentation.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/internals/sourcelink?pivots=windows)

Also you can get more diagnostic details during debugging by changing Xamarin options [as specified in Xamarin forums](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/172334/error-tracing-in-xamarin-forms-any-advice?).